# Python: How to Deserialize the Trained dlib Model Data(.dat) in Python?

Tags: python, c++, deserialization, dlib

I'm studying dlib model in python, and now translating C++ dnn_mmod_dog_hipsterizer code into python code, for comport to using other python module.

In C++ code, the given hipsterizer data is deserialized to net(network), sp(shape predictor), glasses, and mustache. But I can't find out that there is any function that deserializes customly. Only get_frontal_face_detector(), shape_detector(), etc.

```
net_type net;
shape_predictor sp;
matrix<rgb_alpha_pixel> glasses, mustache;
deserialize(argv[1]) >> net >> sp >> glasses >> mustaches;
```

Could you suggest how to use this data in Python?

Comment: What do you mean by *"deserializes customly"*?

Comment: Not 100% of DLib's C++ API is available in Python, too. What is available can be found [here](http://dlib.net/python/index.html). Just as an example `train_shape_predictor(...)` can be serialized with the overload parameter `predictor_output_filename` for serialization.